# How can I toggle MVC Header based on Cookie value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have a regular HTMl header in MVC environment which looks like following HTMl markup:

```
<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">

        <div class="float-left">
            <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("Promotional Sponsorship", "Index", "Applications")</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Navbar" class="float-right">
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Applications", "Index", "Applications")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Vendors", "Index", "Vendors")</li>
                    <li>@ViewBag.UserName</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</header>
```

Now, I want to show/Hide this header based on a cookie value and I do have following Javascript which I thought would do the job. Also, if I put firebug debugger on it, is seems like it is hitting this piece of code but it does not seem to toggle anything based on the Cookie value:

```
script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($.cookie("IsRep") == true) {
            $('#Navbar').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: So what is value of cookie when you run debugger? Note that cookies are strings

Comment: it is actually true/false

Comment: You probably need : $.cookie("IsRep").toLowerCase() == "true"

Comment: @DinoMyte have to check if it exists also if do that to avoid error

Comment: @charlietfl : Yup ! That would be a precautionary step but not required.

Comment: Hit this `$.cookie("IsRep")` in console window and tell us what you see as a result